# A pattern to call sequence of ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chain

I've a method with 4 subsequent ajax calls, which look like:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function( response ){
        $.ajax({
            success: function( response ) {
               ..more calls deeper..
            },
            error: function( ) {
                showError();
            }
        });
    },
    error: function( ) {
        showError();
    }
});
```

Is there any pattern to chain all thouse calls without nesting and duplicating error callback?

Comment: Why are you chaining these calls on the client and not continuing execution on the server?

Comment: If each of the handlers does something different, you can return a single object with the results of each action and loop through the properties of the object and call the relevant handler if the action was successful. If it's a chain, you can call showError() and return  out of the loop early.

Comment: @StuperUser due to use of different REST services (for BL, SSO, 3rd party integration). Ofc we can make a service to bind all those calls into one, but we decided to skip this overhead and do such things at client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$.when(
  // first one
  //data = data1
  $.get("your-url-1-here"),

  // second one
  // data = data2
  $.get("your-url-2-here"),

  // third one
  //data = data3
  $.get("your-url-3-here"),

  // fourth one
  // data = data4
  $.get("your-url-4-here")

).then(function( data1, data2, data3, data4 ) {

  //Do something with data1, data2, data3 and data4

});
```

Comment: I didn't know jQuery could do that. Nice +1

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the duplication of the error callback, just point to the `showError` function like this:

```
error: showError
```

No need to wrap it in a function there

Answer (score -1):

```
var flagIsFinished = false;
function ajax(successCB, errorCB){
  if(!flagIsFinished){
    $.ajax({
      'success':function(){
        ajax(successCB, errorCB);
      }
      'error':errorCB
    });
  }
}
```

Work with a flag. Set it true in the successCB when you're finished. Like this you'll never have to worry how many times you have to run the ajax function, just make sure you test the end condition very well. Otherwise you could get an endless loop with this approach.

Comment: Does the OP need the same success callback for every ajax call? Then, how does the callback know it's the last one? How do you suggest the OP supplies urls to those ajax calls?

Comment: About the url: he left it out in the question, I don't think it's necessary to tell him how to do that. I don't know about the `successCB` though, here I just assumed, given the fact there's not much information provided in the question. If the question gets updated with more information I'm happy to edit my answer ;-)

Comment: The problem is that this kind of recursion is a hassle to manage. If I want to access 4 different urls, I'd have to store those in a array, and keep track of some kind of counter.

Comment: That's true. As I said, if this would be a requirement I'll edit my answer